# 'Activate element with one click' setting does not work

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.1
Although I set the option 'Activate element with one click' in xfce4-settings-manager / File manager settings / Behavior dialogue I still need to use double click on the Create launcher icon (right click on an empty part of desktop) to select a Working directory.

Where can i report this (i admit little) bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the [XFCE launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce-project) and submit a bug report. However, I think there is a bug report already out there that is the exact error you are mentioning, which you can [access here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfdesktop/+bug/58415).